# How to determine a subset selecting a percentage of population?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I would need to compute the percentage of a population. Specifically, I would need the 10% of the initial population in order to determine a new subset. 
I tried using

```
proc sql;
select time, 
      count(*)*0.1
from table1
group by 1;
quit;
```

and it works, as I have the percentage of population that I wanted. However, I have difficulties in finding a way that can allow me to include another condition (`where var1>0 and var2=24`) where variables are from the original dataset (i.e. `var1` and `var2` are from table1). 
Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have 1,000 items (row) from which you want a 10% random sample.

`Proc SURVEYSELECT` is probably the best way to select samples.

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 1000; output; end;
run;

proc surveyselect noprint data=have method=srs rate=10 out=want;
run;
```

A SQL selection based on a random number can provide a crude analog but does not produce a precise 10% sampling rate.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select id from have
  where rand('uniform') <= 0.10  %* roughly 10% of a uniform distribution;
;
```

There are other ways, such as DATA step with a `k/n` algorithm.

```
data want;
  call streaminit(123);

  do k=0.10*N by 0 while (k > 0);
    set have nobs=n;

    if rand('UNIFORM') <= k/n then do;
      k + (-1);
      output;
    end;
    n +(-1);
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. In the way that you suggested, could I select the variables (or all the variables) from my original dataset, even if I am selecting the 10%? My doubt was in using those variables as it has not been possible using count(*) in proc sql.

Comment: All three examples select the entire row, so all variables would be available.  Use the data set options `(KEEP=<list of variables>)` if you want to reduce the number of **variables** in the sample data set.

Comment: Thank you Richard